# Create same code number of repeated cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to create a formula that:

1. Shows unique same number for each item
2. Creates a new ID (the max existing value for code +1) for a new item based on the existing codes and items.

For example:

| Code | Item |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | A |
| 1001 | B |
| 1002 | C |
| 1000 | A |
| 1000 | A |
| 1002 | C |

So, if i add item "D" its code would be 1004, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be defining a list against each letter. How many letter can be for your actual case? With your given sample data you can try below-

```
=XLOOKUP(B2,{"A","B","C","D","E","F"},{1000,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005})
```

[image]

> ***Edit:*** You can also try-

```
=IF(B2:B20="","",1000+XMATCH(B2:B20,SORT(UNIQUE(B2:B20)),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've used the letters as examples, the table I'm working on contains strings of events (eg: event 1, event 2 and even 3) and it could be n events. Thats why I need that when a new event is added it creates a new code (+1 from the maximum of the previous codes)